# Find the dimension of a kernel of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $\phi$ is a linear transformation.
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\\
\phi: \mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{W} \quad \phi(f) = f + f^{'} \quad \phi \text{ is linear}
$$

Find $dim \: ker \phi$.

So I only come up with the following.

$$
f \in ker \phi \iff f(x) + f^{'}(x) = 0 \quad \forall x
$$

Then $f(x) = Ce^{-x}$ for some constant $C$. Could I say that function $f(x) = e^{-x}$ forms a basis of a kernel and $dim \: ker \phi = 1$?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: What does $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\\
\phi: \mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{W}$$ mean? I guess you meant $\phi:\mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{W}$ where $V\subset\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ but that does not specify $V$ enough. If $V$ contains the function $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ (e.g. if $V$ is the subspace of differentiable functions, or the subspace of smooth functions) then your solution is correct. But if it does not (for instance if $V$ is the subspace of polynomial functions) then $\ker \phi=\{0\}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval it's assumed that V is a subspace of differentiable functions

Comment: Of course, this is mandatory for $\phi$ to be defined. But as previously shown in my examples, it does not specify $V$ enough.